# Fubini's theorem for finite dimensional vector space?

Tags: measure-theory, vector-spaces

In Weil's *Basic Number Theory*, the author used Fubini's theorem to show that finite dimensional subspace over locally compact field $F$ has measure zero. While I know this result, I don't know how Fubini's theorem can be used for finite dimensional vector space rather than product $\prod^n X_i$. Is there any homeomorphism between $n$-dimensional vector space over $F$ and $F^n$ s.t. it preserves the property of being measure zero?

Comment: You need to provide more information. Is there a measure defined on $F$?  If so, then using the standard isomorphism between a $n$-dimensional vector space over $F$ and $F^n$, we can define a measure on the $n$-dimensional vector space over $F$.  And then, the isomorphism will be preserve measure, in particular the property of being measure zero.

Comment: I'm sorry. I was considering about a Haar measure on $F^n$. It is nice that the standard isomorphism is measure-preserving. While it sounds obvious, I couldn't find it in my textbook. Thank you!

Comment: There is no standard isomorphism for an abstract $F$-vector space. Every basis gives rise to an isomorphism, but none of them is privileged. And such an isomorphism need not quite be measure-preserving (once we have Haar measures defined on both spaces), but what it does is multiply measures by a constant [but Haar measure is anyway only unique up to constant factors], so null sets (and only null sets) are mapped to null sets.

Comment: @DanielFischer The "standard" isomorphism I meant is precisely the one defined by peeking one basis.  Of course, different basis will correspond to different isomorphisms.

Comment: @MathOverStackExchange That is precisely why I said we need more information.  IF you just have a measure defined on $F$, then peek a basis in $V$, the $n$-dimensional vector over $F$. Such basis determines an isomorphism between $V$ and $F^n$. It is trivial to transport (by the isomorphism) the product measure on $F^n$ to $V$. With such measure on $V$, then the isomorphism between $V$ and $F^n$ is obviously measure-preserving, and you can easily apply Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: On the other hand, if your start point is a Haar measure $\mu_V$ on $V$, the $n$-dimensional vector space, and a Haar measure $\mu_F$ on $F$. Then peek  a basis in $V$,  such basis determines an isomorphism between $V$ and $F^n$. The product measure $\mu_{F^n}$ is a Haar measure on $F^n$.  And when you transport it to $V$ (by the isomorphism) you get $\mu_2$, another  Haar measure on $V$. The isomorphism is measure-preserving between $(V,\mu_2)$ and $(F^n, \mu_{F^n})$. So you can easily apply Fubini's theorem to prove the result for $\mu_2$.  (Continue)

Comment: To complete the proof note that any two Haar measure on $V$ differ by a constant factor. So we can conclude the result is also true for $\mu_V$: any finite dimensional subspace has $\mu_V$-measure zero.

Comment: I didn't think that Haar measure would do the job in that way. Thanks a lot!